# Stop Autoplay of Videos on opening Websites

Tags: 16.04, browser, autostart

Whenever I open a new website, some websites start playing some kind of videos(like advertisement) automatically. This consumes my data and I want to stop autoplaying of such videos.

How can I stop the autoplaying of videos in Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

Provided you use Firefox, you could use the [noscript](https://noscript.net/) extension.
This free, open source add-on allows JavaScript, Java and Flash to be executed only on the sites you choose.